# "Like" counter, increment value by click in django

Tags: django, django-templates, increment

Im trying to make simple button that will increament my value by 1 in database and show it on page.

I found something on [Django - How to increment integer field from user input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16431822/django-how-to-increment-integer-field-from-user-input) but it doesn't solve problem.

My code in views.py:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    id = request.POST.get('slug')
    vote = request.POST.get('voo')
    glosy = request.POST.get('glosy')
    git = Photo.objects.all().filter(pk=id, votes = vote)
    vote = int(vote)+1


    p = Photo.objects.get(pk=id)
    print p.votes3
    p.votes3 += 1
    print p.votes3
    p.save()

    Photo.objects.all().filter(pk=id).update(votes3=10)
```

and my code in template:

```
{% extends "photologue/root.html" %}

{% load photologue_tags i18n %}
{% load comments %}

{% block title %}{{ obj.title }}{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

{% load static %}

  <script src="{% static 'js/pinol-ajax.js' %}"></script>
<script>

  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '876940702346526',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.2'
    });
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>

    <div class="row col-lg-12">
        <h1 class="page-header">{{ obj.title }}</h1>
        <p class="muted"><small>{% trans "Published" %} {{ obj.date_added }}</small></p>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            {% if obj.caption %}<p>{{ obj.caption|safe }}</p>{% endif %}
              <a href="{{pho.image.url}}" data-lightbox="roadtrip" alt = "">
                <img src="{{ pho.get_display_url }}" class="thumbnail" alt="{{ obj.title }}"></a>


<br>        
<!-- <button id="likes" data-catid="{{obj.title}}" class="btn btn-primary" type="button"> Like  </button> {{ pho.votes }}  {{ object.view_count }} --> 
<strong id="like_count">{{ pho.votes }}</strong> people like this photo

{% if user.is_authenticated %}
<form action="" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
      <button type="submit" value="preview" name="Preview">HUEHUE</button> 

{% endif %}            
<div class="fb-share-button"  data-layout="button_count"></div>

            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            {% if pho.public_galleries %}
                <p>{% trans "This photo is found in the following galleries" %}:</p>
                <table>
                    {% for gallery in pho.public_galleries %}
                        <tr>
                            <td>{% previous_in_gallery pho gallery %}</td>
                            <td class="text-center"><a href="">{{ gallery.title }}</a></td>
                            <td>{% next_in_gallery pho gallery %}</td>
                        </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                </table>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}fluent_comments/css/ajaxcomments.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}fluent_comments/js/ajaxcomments.js"></script>

<div class="fb-like" data-href="{{request.META.HTTP_HOST}}" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="{{request.META.HTTP_HOST}}" data-numposts="5" data-colorscheme="light"></div>
<!-- {{request.META.HTTP_HOST}}{{request.get_full_path}} -->
{% render_comment_list for pho %}

{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    {% render_comment_form for pho %}
{% else %}
    Zaloguj się aby dodawać komentarze! :)
{% endif %}


            {% endif %}


{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What error do you see ?

Also, what is the value of the `slug2` variable you use to filter ? This should be passed through the post, so you need to add a hidden input in your form that will pass the value of the slug2... Something like this:

```
<input type='hidden' value='{{ slug2 }}' name='slug2' />
```

And then in your view get the value from the `POST` dictionary:

```
slug2  = request.POST.get('slug2')
```

---

*Update* (after seeing OP's code): You need to pass the `slug` to your form action . So, using something like this:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit" value="preview" name="Preview">HUEHUE</button> 
</form>
{% endif %}
```

Will *not* work since you'll just visit again the calling view (an empty action POSTS to the current URL -- the action parameter needs to have a value).

I don't know the url name of your `Photo_det` view, so let's say that it is called `photo_det` (this is defined in `urls.py`). Your form should be something like this

```
<form action="{% url 'photo_det' photo.slug %}" method="post">
```

in order for the form action to be the `Photo_det` function view.

Comment: The page is refreshing but counter on page dont increase. I will check your solution and tell you what happen

Comment: If it doesn't work please provide the full template and view.

Comment: after i change form action i get error:

"Reverse for 'photo_det' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []"

Comment: Yes. You need to put the name of your view there instead of ``photo_det`` - please check this out https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns

Comment: Everything wroks but doesn't work save() method and update.

I've updated the code on first post so you can check it.

Comment: Have you updated your form action ? You seem to be passing some parameters to your view (slug, voo, etc) that aren't passed through your form. Something does nto feel right ...

Comment: Yes my form looks now: "{% url 'photologue:photo_det' pho.slug %}"

Comment: Well the ``slug`` won't be contained in the POST dictionary but will be instead a parameter to your view! Please try to understand the difference between captured view parameters (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#named-groups) and request GET/POST parameters !