# Implementing pageviews in Django

Tags: python, django

I am working on a small a small website and I want to display the total views of every object in the detail view. But sincerely, I don't know how to actualise this. Let me post my models.py and views.py

Models.py

```
class Music(models.Model):
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(default='', blank=True, unique=True)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(blank=False)
    audio_file = models.FileField(default='')
    uploaded_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-uploaded_date']

    def save(self):
        self.uploaded_date = timezone.now()
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super(Music, self).save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title + ' by ' + self.artist

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('music:detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
```

Views.py

```
        return Music.objects.order_by('-uploaded_date')


def detail(request, slug):
    latest_posts = Music.objects.order_by('-uploaded_date')[:5]
    song = get_object_or_404(Music, slug=slug)
    comments = Comment.objects.filter(post=song)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        comment_form = CommentForm(request.POST or None)
        if comment_form.is_valid():
            comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
            comment.post = song
            comment.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(song.get_absolute_url())
    else:
        comment_form = CommentForm()

    context = {
        'latest_posts': latest_posts,
        'song': song,
        'comments': comments,
        'comment_form': comment_form,
    }
    return render(request, 'music/detail.html', context)
```

Comment: How are you storing page views? Are you asking how you can record when a page is viewed and then later display it in the template? What counts as a page being viewed? The `detail` view function for that object being invoked because someone requested it?

Comment: I don't have any attribute that stores page views. And yes am asking of how I can record when a page is viewed and then later display it in the template without altering the uploaded_date attribute

Answer (score 0):

You can add an `IntegerField` to your `Music` model called `page_views`:

```py
class Music(models.Model):
    ...
    page_views = IntegerField(default=0)
```

Then borrowing from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24318837/9374673) you can increment `views` for the individual `song` from your `detail` view whenever the page is requested:

```py
def detail(request, slug):
    latest_posts = Music.objects.order_by('-uploaded_date')[:5]
    song = get_object_or_404(Music, slug=slug)
    comments = Comment.objects.filter(post=song)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        comment_form = CommentForm(request.POST or None)
        if comment_form.is_valid():
            comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
            comment.post = song
            comment.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(song.get_absolute_url())
    else:
        comment_form = CommentForm()
        song.update(page_views=F('page_views') + 1) # Add this line here so it's not updated on POST

    context = {
        'latest_posts': latest_posts,
        'song': song,
        'comments': comments,
        'comment_form': comment_form,
    }
    return render(request, 'music/detail.html', context)
```

Note that you may not want to count someone adding a comment through the form as another view for the page, so it's up to you how you define when the count actually gets incremented. This is just a really basic way to count how many times the page is requested.